# Visual Transformers predict() returning same prediction output for all values in test inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, transformer-model

Hello So Recently I was used some implementation of visual transformers and tried to implement it. on validation and testing MAE = 27. and when i decided to make model predict on same datasets it gave me obscure numbers. can anyone help me to solve it?

```py
class VisionTransformer(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(
        self,
        image_size,
        patch_size,
        num_layers,
        num_classes,
        d_model,
        num_heads,
        mlp_dim,
        channels=3,
        dropout=0.1,
    ):
        super(VisionTransformer, self).__init__()
        num_patches = (image_size // patch_size) ** 2
        self.patch_dim = channels * patch_size ** 2

        self.patch_size = patch_size
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        self.rescale = Rescaling(1./255)
        self.pos_emb = self.add_weight(
            "pos_emb", shape=(1, num_patches + 1, d_model)
        )
        self.class_emb = self.add_weight("class_emb", shape=(1, 1, d_model))
        self.patch_proj = Dense(d_model)
        self.enc_layers = [
            TransformerBlock(d_model, num_heads, mlp_dim, dropout)
            for _ in range(num_layers)
        ]
        self.mlp_head = tf.keras.Sequential(
            [
                Dense(mlp_dim, activation=tfa.activations.gelu),
                Dropout(dropout),
                Dense(num_classes),
            ]
        )

    def extract_patches(self, images):
        batch_size = tf.shape(images)[0]
        patches = tf.image.extract_patches(
            images=images,
            sizes=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
            strides=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
            rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
            padding="VALID",
        )
        patches = tf.reshape(patches, [batch_size, -1, self.patch_dim])
        return patches

    def call(self, x, training):
        batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0]
        x = self.rescale(x)
        patches = self.extract_patches(x)
        x = self.patch_proj(patches)

        class_emb = tf.broadcast_to(
            self.class_emb, [batch_size, 1, self.d_model]
        )
        x = tf.concat([class_emb, x], axis=1)
        x = x + self.pos_emb

        for layer in self.enc_layers:
            x = layer(x, training)

        # First (class token) is used for classification
        x = self.mlp_head(x[:, 0])
        return x
```

```py
model.predict(datasetTrain)
```

And it gave me same values for each year (i think mae would be 900 at min) what just happened??